# is there way to resole this issue "_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)"

Tags: flutter, dart, null

[image]i created a Product model to retrive information from json.But i encounter this issue every time i run the app."type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast".

I use the "late intializer" but it did not run.

Comment: Something that's null is not a String. Simple as that. If you maybe want a nullable String you should write `as String?` (note the question mark)

Comment: change this : `imag: map['imag'] as String` in  `imag: map['imag'] ?? ""` or make `imag` as nullable by question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Your ProductModel had no "imag" member. Did you maybe mean "image"?

What do you want to happen, if there is no image in your data?

Did you maybe want a nullable string (`string?`) for your image? If so, then use that as datatype instead of `string`.

If there *must* be an image and it must be named "imag", then you need to repair your JSON. Because it does not have it.

Comment: yes i wanted it nullible just in case the image does not load and if has no image to.

Comment: yes i mean "imag" as "image" i made a typo